# Letting a folder on one disk redirect to a folder on a second disk. How?

Tags: windows-vista, file-management, redirection

I bought a powerful desktop system with two hard disks. Windows Vista came pre-installed on the `D:` disk. My secondary disk received the letter `E:`.

Really annoying, but when I just had the system, it didn't bother me much. I changed the `E:` disk to `B:` because the computer management couldn't alter the drive letter for the D: disk. (Something with boot information or primary disk or whatever…)

Now, I know I can create a folder on the `D:` disk which would point to the root folder of another disk. This took away the problem I had simply because my secondary disk is just for data storage.

But now I want to create a folder `D:\Companyname` and I want this folder to be linked to `B:\Companyname`… How do I link one folder to another without installing additional software?

Why I need this? Simple. I started working on a Delphi project and some [beep][beep] has used lots and lots of hard-coded path names in the code. I can't change those paths because I have just precompiled units.

And please, don't suggest re-installations or repartitioning the disks because that would be too much trouble for a single project. Besides, I don't want to mess up a good system by messing up the file/disk system. I just need this for the three weeks that I'm working on this project... (And I would use a Virtual machine for this if I had a Vista virtual machine. But I don't have one.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Vista and Windows 7 bring you the MKLINK command.

```
MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
                symbolic link.
        /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link 
                refers to.
```

Comment: I apologise for the code formatting, but it's really SuperUser's fault :)